# Is there a way to use methods created by mongoose on the client side?

Tags: mongoose, redux, mern

I would like to use a method I created with mongoose in my react component (print out the full name of a user). Is this possible? I've tried using .virtual and .methods but they don't seem be passed in the response of my API.

React component:

```
render() {
    const { user } = this.props.auth;

    return (
      <div>{user.fullName()}</div>
    );
}
```

User Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  registerDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  profile: {
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String
    },
    nickname: {
      type: String
    }
  }
});

UserSchema.virtual('fullName').get(function() {
  return this.profile.firstName + (' ' + this.profile.lastName) || '';
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```

API:

```
router.get('/user', auth, (req, res) => {
  User.findById(req.user.id)
    .select('-password')
    .then(user => res.json(user));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

You can pass a virtuals: true option to toJSON.

In my Schema:

```
UserSchema.set('toJSON', { virtuals: true });
```